# Open the existing Android project and take less time to build with Gradle?

Tags: android, performance, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I just complete Applied CSwithAndroid workshop and in every unit there is a starter code to start project.

When we open the project, it will take a lot of time to build gradle. My colleagues are also effected, and some newcomer in Android developement just give up some time.

Comment: Already edited guys Help wanted ?

Comment: This is different question so remove duplicate tag @cricket_007

Comment: No. Create a new post

Comment: But I was ban to create a new post.\

Comment: You can go to the help center to see why that is and what you can do about it.

Comment: Yeah, I know. That why I updated it but still tag with a duplicate.